# Using email to link two graphs

Tags: sparql

If I have two following two graphs:

```
<http://example.com/graph1>

:A foaf:mbox "A@example.com"
```

and

```
<http://example.com/graph2>

:B foaf:mbox "a@EXAMPLE.com";
foaf:phone "123456878" .
```

How can I get:

```
----------------------
| person | phone     |
======================
| A      |"123456878"|
----------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like the following?  Since the email addresses don't use the same case, I've normalized them using **[lcase](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-lcase)**.

```
select ?person ?phone {
  graph ?g { ?person foaf:mbox ?email1 }
  graph ?h { ?person_ foaf:mbox ?email2 ; foaf:phone ?phone }
  filter (lcase(?email1) = lcase(?email2))
}
```

Comment: Hm, would it be possible to use case insensitive regex like `filter regex(?email1, concat("^", ?email2, "$"), "i")`? if so, what would be the effect on performance?

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz That wouldn't really be safe.  The email address can contain characters that have meaning in regexes.  E.g., `a@example.com` would match `a@example_com`, since `.` is a wildcard.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I tried with lcase but using `BIND` which was OK in one direction but not in both. Now I'll try with filter. Is just a omission the there is no `where`? And I guess instead of `?g` I should put my actual graph URI.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov `where` is optional. See [the grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#rWhereClause) for reference.

Comment: wrt to `?g`, Joshua made an assumption here. You mentioned some graph, hence a variable. The query above will match any two graphs connected by the email value. If you replace the `?g` variable with a URI you will only try connecting two specific graphs

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz yes, it's from two specific graphs as I wrote, `<http://example.com/graph1>` and `<http://example.com/graph2>. Anyway, @JoshuaTaylor, this query takes hours in my case. Now the question is how to update both graphs to have all emails lowercase? (then I'll run the query without filter - should be much faster)